# When should I use nn.ModuleList and when should I use nn.Sequential?

Tags: pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and one thing that I don't quite understand is the usage of `nn.ModuleList` and `nn.Sequential`. Can I know when I should use one over the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html) does not have a `forward` method, but [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html?highlight=nn%20sequential#torch.nn.Sequential) does have one. So you can wrap several modules in `nn.Sequential` and run it on the input.

`nn.ModuleList` is just a Python *list* (though it's useful since the parameters can be discovered and trained via an optimizer). While `nn.Sequential` is a module that sequentially runs the component on the input.

Answer (score 4):

Both `nn.ModuleList` and `nn.Sequential` are containers that contains pytorch nn modules.

[`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html) just stores a list [`nn.Modules`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) and it does not have a `forward()` method. So you can not call it like a normal module.

On the other hand, [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) also contains a list of modules, but you need to make sure that output from current module can be fed into its next module, otherwise, you will get an error.
You can think `nn.Sequential` as a module and you can call it with a input like the normal module.

You can define a ModuleList, but you can not call this `mlist` with input, this will cause an error:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

mlist = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(5)])
x = torch.rand(64, 10)

out = mlist(x)  # this will cause an error
```

For `nn.Sequential`, this is not the case:

```py
seqlist = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 10), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(10, 20))

x = torch.random(64, 10)
out = seqlist(x)  # runs fine, shape of out: (64, 20)
```

Ref:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-should-i-use-nn-modulelist-and-when-should-i-use-nn-sequential/5463/2