# What is the difference between PyTorch nn.Sequential and nn.ModuleList?

Tags: python, pytorch

If one wants to create a module consisting of multiple layers from a list, one may proceed in a following way:

```
# here we fill the python list containing the layers 

module = nn.Sequential(*layer_list)
# or 
module = nn.ModuleList(layer_list)
```

Are both ways completely equivalent or there is some difference? Looking in the shell at following example:

```
model1 = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(3)])
model2 = nn.Sequential(*[nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(3)])
model1
# ModuleList(
#  (0): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
#  (1): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
#  (2): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
# )
model2
# Sequential(
#   (0): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
#   (1): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
#   (2): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
# )
```

I would suppose that both options do essentialy the same.

Comment: how about [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-should-i-use-nn-modulelist-and-when-should-i-use-nn-sequential/5463/4)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544051/when-should-i-use-nn-modulelist-and-when-should-i-use-nn-sequential